# Validate FQDN in C#

Tags: c#, regex, fqdn

Does anyone have a Regular Expression to validate legal FQDN?

Now, I use on this regex:

```
(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.|-)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}(?!-)\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)
```

However this regex results in "aa.a" not being valid while "aa.aa" is valid.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a shorter pattern:

```
(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)
```

As for why the pattern determines "aa.a" as invalid and "aa.aa" as valid, it's because of the `{2,}` - if you change the 2 to a 1 so that it's

```
(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,})$)
```

it should deem both "aa.a" and "aa.aa" as valid.

```
string pattern = @"(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,})$)";
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("aa.a", pattern);
```

`isMatch` is TRUE for me.

Comment: I do that but it's not work, again it determines "aa.a" as invalid and "aa.aa" as valid. can you explain me what the meaning of "{1,}" instead "{2,}"?

Comment: Using the pattern with `{1.}` "aa.a" validates for me. Curly braces specify a specific amount of repetition so `{1,}` requires at least 1 repetition and `{2,}` requires at least 2.

Comment: Additional question, what are the diffrents between the pattern that you suggest me to the pattern that I use?

Comment: Only difference is that yours has `(?!-).?)` for the last dot and the one I posted has `\.?)`. The `?!` in yours is using a _negative lookahead assertion_ ("match something not followed by something else").

Comment: now I want to allow also "aa.a10", I change the regex to: (@"(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$)") but it's not work, do you know why?

Comment: @RRR: It works for me...try putting isolating the pattern with your "aa.a10" entry.

Answer (score 4):

I think this could also be an option especially if the FQDN will later be used along with System.Uri:

```
var isWellFormed = Uri.CheckHostName(stringToCheck).Equals(UriHostNameType.Dns);
```

Note that this code considers partially qualified domain names to be well formed.