# Bash based regex domain name validation

Tags: regex, bash, dns

I want to create a script that will add new domains to our DNS Servers. 
I found that [Fully qualified domain name validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809631/fully-qualified-domain-name-validation?answertab=active#tab-top) REGEX.
However, when I use it with sed, it is not working as I would expect:

```
echo test | sed  '/(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)/p'  
--------
Output is: 
test
echo test.com | sed  '/(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)/p'  
--------
Output is: 
test.com
```

I expected that the output of the first command should be a blank line.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: it's not matching your string at all. try `sed -n` to confirm.

Answer (score 14):

I find this to be a more comprehensive regex:

`(?=^.{4,253}$)(^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,}|xn--[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])$)`

- [RFC 1034§3:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3) Allows for a length of 4-25**3**, with the shortest operational domain I'm aware of, "t.co", still matching where the other answers don't. 255 bytes is the maximum length, minus the length octet for each label (TLD and "primary" subdomain) gives us 253: `(?=^.{4,253}$)`

  - [RFC 3696§2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-2): Single-letter TLDs *are* technically permitted, meaning the minimum length would be 3, but as there are currently no single-letter TLDs a minimum length of 4 is practical.
- [RFC 1034§3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3): Allows numbers in subdomains, which Conor Clafferty's apparently doesn't (by not distinguishing other subdomains from "primary" subdomains -- i.e. the domain you register -- which the DNS spec doesn't)
- [RFC 1034§3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3): Restricts individual labels to 63 characters, permitting hyphens in the middle while restricting the beginning and end to alphanumerics `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)`
- Requires a two-letter or larger TLD, but may be [punycoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode#Internationalized_domain_names) `([a-zA-Z]{2,}|xn--[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])`

  - [RFC 3696§2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696#section-2): The DNS spec technically permits numerics in the TLD, as well as single-letter TLDs; however, there are currently no single-letter TLDs or TLDs with numbers currently, and all-numeric TLDs are not permitted, so this part of the regex has been simplified to `[a-zA-Z]{2,}`.

    --OR--
  - [RFC 3490§5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490#section-5): an internationalized domain name ccTLD (IDN ccTLD) may be punycoded, as indicated by an "xn--" prefix, after which it may contain letters, numbers, or hyphens. This approximates to `xn--[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]`

    Be aware that this pattern does not *validate* a punycode TLD! Invalid punycode will be tolerated, e.g. "xn--qqqq", because attempting to validate punycode against the appropriate encoding mechanisms is beyond the scope of a regular expression. While punycode itself technically permits an encoded string ending in a hyphen, [RFC 3492§5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492#section-5) observes and respects the IDNA limitation that labels may not end in a hyphen.

EDIT 02/2021: Hat tip to [user2241415](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2241415/) for pointing out that IDN ccTLDs did not match the previously-specified regex.

Comment: Thank you for being so precise, explaining yourself, and citing sources. Helps a lot in making a quick, informed choice.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.. I've also coded a bash function called isdom, so I can call it with 'isdom string' and it responds yes/no based on this regexp..

Comment: why no work? echo example.com|grep -P '(?=^.{4,253}$)(^(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){,61}[a-zA-Z])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)'

Comment: @roothahn please see my edit. Apparently some interpretations of PCRE (heh) don't like implicit lower bounds (`{,61}`) so I added an explicit lower bound (`{0,61}`) and it plays much nicer with grep: `echo example.com|grep -P '(?=^.{4,253}$)(^(?:[a-zA-Z](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)'`

Comment: it doesn't seem to validate new TLDs like - test.xn--kpu716f (per https://www.swcs.com.au/tld.htm )

Comment: @user2241415 edited in an update that matches IDN ccTLDs!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a question mark in your regex :

`(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(`**?**`:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)`

You can test your regex [here](http://rubular.com/r/QmX59URV8D)

You can do what you want with grep :

```
$ echo test.com | grep -P '(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)'
test.com
$ echo test | grep -P '(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)'
$
```

Comment: if I tested test.-com, it passes. that's not valid,right?

Comment: Didn't work for me.. Tryit yourself for example: `echo fireb | grep -P '(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)'`. It will return: fireb. But it is not a domain name. Another example: `echo berif_novp | grep -P '(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)'`. Returns: berif_novp, but this is not a domain too. Even trying on rubular.com **it is matching strings that are not domains.**

Comment: The problem with this regex is that it violates certain rules about domains: 1. domains cannot have underscores; 2. labels may not *start* or *end* with a hyphen (first and last characters of each label must be alphanumeric); 3. labels *can* be entirely numeric (except TLD... maybe), so `(?!\d+\.)` is inappropriate; 4. the `?` quantifier on `\.` in the main grouping is incorrect, as it allows domains with no periods

Answer (score 1):

No `sed` implementation I am aware of supports the various Perl extensions you are using in that regex.  Try with Perl or `grep -P` or `pcregrep`, or simplify the regex to something `sed` can cope with.  Here is a quick and dirty adaptation which splits the regex into a script of three different regexes, and rejects when something fails to match (or matches, in the middlemost case).

```
echo 'test' | sed -r '/^.{5,254}$/!d
    /^([^.]*\.)*[0-9]+\./d   # Seems incorrect; 112.com is valid
    /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+([a-zA-Z]{2,})$/!d'  # should disallow underscore
    # also, what's with the question mark after the literal dot?
```

This also completely fails to accept IDNA domains (which can contain dashes and numbers in the TLD, among other things) so I would definitely not recommend this, but hopefully it shows you how to adapt something like this to `sed` if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre-Louis' answer didn't quite work for me. e.g. "kittens" is considered a domain name.
I added one slight adjustment to ensure that the domain at least had a dot in it.

```
(?=^.{5,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+\.(?:[a-z]{2,})$)
```

Theres an extra `\.` just before it reads the last portion of the domain.

Comment: shouldn't the beginning actually be `(?=^.{4,254}$)` ? "t.co" is a valid domain (and currently in use!), and is only 4 characters long...

Comment: The "fix" is incorrect. The spurious dot now allows for two consecutive dots before the TLD. A better fix would be to remove the question mark after the literal dot which was already there (but it's technically incorrect; e.g. `dk` alone is a valid domain name).

Answer (score 0):

I use `grep -P` to do this.

```
echo test | grep -P "^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$" 
--------
Output is: 

echo www.test.com | grep -P "^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$"
--------
Output is: www.test.com
```

Comment: hey, this worked for me. Could you explain this regex for me to understand clearly?

Answer (score -2):

if the domain has to exist you can try:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

for h in "bert" "ernie" "www.google.com"
do
    host $h 2>&1 > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$h is a FQDN"
    else
        echo "$h is not a FQDN"
    fi
done

jalderman@mba:/tmp$ ./test.sh 
bert is not a FQDN
ernie is not a FQDN
www.google.com is a FQDN
```