# Autohotkey: regex not behaving as expected

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I want regex to match web addresses such as `http://www.example.com`, `example.co.uk`, `en.example.com` etc. I've been using `^(https?://|www\.|)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$` and testing it on http://regexpal.com/, and it seems to work exactly as it should.

However, when I put it in autohotkey, it seems to match extra things like `example` and `example.something`, when it shouldn't. It then doesn't match things like `example.com/something` and `example.com/something.html` when it should.

```
If RegExMatch(Clipboard, "^(https?://|www\.|)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$")
    Msgbox, it matches
else
    Msgbox, it doesn't
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching URLs, host names etc is a problem solved many times; I suggest you adapt some standard regex. Perhaps [SO question: Fully qualified domain name validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809631/fully-qualified-domain-name-validation) is helpful.

---

If you're composing the regex as an exercise:

Does it really match the string `example`? You firmly assert the string to contain a `.`, so it never should. Maybe AHK doesn't escape `.` the standard way?

If `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` should match top level domain, you forgot about `.info`.

You may want to allow strings of whitespace of arbitrary length at the end and beginning, if you accidentally copied some such into the clipboard. I.e. `^\s*your-regex-thingy\s*$`

`example.something` is a match, because it begins with the empty string, follows with a sequence of 1 or more alphanumerics (or `-`, `.`), one `.`, 2 or 3 letters, and ends with a sequence of non-whitespace.

`example.com/something.html` might fail to match if the entire substring `example.com` is matched by the group `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+`. It shouldn't if the regex engine is correctly implemented, though. Perhaps you need to escape `+`, `|` or some such, engines have varying conventions on such (i.e. `sed` and `pcre` have differing opinions on `+` and `(` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I would go even as far as allowing not just whitespaces, but other *noise* sorrounding the URL in the clipboard. In other words, I would simply remove the `^` and `$`. You never know what browsers or word processors actually do if you copy stuff, especially if they are from Microsoft ;) For instance, JavaScript can *"hijack"* your clipboard, here's an [example](http://www.firstpost.com/politics/volunteers-or-vigilantes-the-perils-of-aaps-anarchic-politics-1328297.html). Try to copy something from the news and paste it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it *was* an escaping problem. I'd changed the escape character to /, so I needed two of them to get the regex to work properly.