# regular expression for a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I want that form submit when user enter their domain without `https://` or `http://` or `/` at the end.what is the regular expression for this.

```
https://google.com   wrong
http://google.com    wrong
google.com           correct
subdomain.google.com correct
google.com/          wrong
```

Please tell me what is the regular expression for this

Comment: What about `google.` or `google.com/something` or just `google`?

Comment: `google.com/something` not allowed neither just `google` allowed .thanks for point this issue

Comment: How are you using the submitted data? It's easy to do a server DNS lookup instead of trying to restrict user input.

Comment: this is a form validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!https?:\/\/)\w+(\.\w+)+$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/41

```
^(?!https?:\/\/)(?!.*?\/$)[\w./]+$
```

You can try this is you have inputs like `google.com/something`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/40

Comment: Just `^[\w.]+$` would do the same thing.

Comment: will you please tell me why i am getting `-1` when using your expression [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/r350ck2t/)

Comment: @user3262732 try putting it in a delimiter.`/^(?!https?://)\w+(\.\w+)+$/`

Comment: one last thing what if i checked that string not contain `/` at the start or end of a simple string

Comment: @user3262732 the regex wont allow `/` at the start or end.You can try in the demo.

Comment: this is work fine . thanks for the help but now i want to validate another input field. that field contain `foldername` and i want to test the input will never contain `/` at the start or at the end of the string

Comment: @user3262732 it would be better if you can ask a new question as we will have to modify the accepted answer.any ways try `\w+(/\w+)*`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @vks's answer, I would do the more simple: `^[\w.]+\.[a-z]+$`.  This makes sure that has a word, and that there is a period "." and then a few more lowercase letters.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a "fully qualified domain name" (FQDN), not a URL. FQDN regexp is the following (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204811/240443)):

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)
```

Simpler regular expressions can result in FQDNs that violate the RFC, by being too long, by allowing disallowed characters, or characters in disallowed positions (e.g. `-.-`, `a..a` or `__.com` would be matched my some of the other suggestions on this page, while not being valid FQDNs).