# How to check whether string matches that of a domain

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have written a piece of code to test whether a string matches a domain like this:

```
host=$1
if [[ $host =~ ^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$ ]] ; then
    echo "it is a domain!"
fi
```

With help from [this website](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/domain-name-regular-expression-example/) but for some reason, the above is not working.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: i think bash regex won't support lookarounds. And you're not allowed to use regex inside double quotes.

Comment: I have tried without quotes and still not working!

Comment: ya, bash won't support lookarounds.. you may use perl.

Comment: "regular expressions" are not a specific language, but more of a paradigm. If you have an object written in Java, you can't copy-paste it to C++. If you have a regex written in PCRE, you can't copy-paste it to ERE.

Comment: Yes I understand that I am now using the regex from a question focusing on bash code, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809631/fully-qualified-domain-name-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash regex doesn't have lookaround, you can use Perl Regex with `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -oP '^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$' <<< "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1;then
echo valid
else
echo invalid
fi
```